# Twitter Followers - Want to jump from page 1 to 3

Tags: php, api, twitter, yii, pagination

I'm trying to to display all Twitter followers for specific account in PHP, using this API request

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json
```

As per this page [Cursoring - Twitter Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/cursoring) I have the use the next cursor to receive the next batch of responses.

That will allow me to make pagination button for the next page and previous page since I don't know what is the value of next_cursor for 3rd,4th, ... pages.

Is there a way to make paging links like [1](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/cursoring),[2],[3],[4],[5],[..] so I can jump to the 3rd page without visiting the 2nd page?

I'm using Yii, Abraham Williams TwitterOAuth class.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this method to obtain all twitter followers of an account with Abraham Williams TwitterOAuth class:

```
$arrayFollowersIds = array();
// Cursor pointing the first page
$cursorFollowers = -1;
for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
    // If we have reached the last page...
    if ($cursorFollowers == 0) break;

    $followersArray = get_object_vars($connection->get('followers/ids', array('user_id' => $targetUserId, 'cursor' => $cursorFollowers)));
    if (array_key_exists('ids', $followersArray)) {
        $cursorFollowersActual = $followersArray['next_cursor'];
        $arrayFollowersIds = array_merge($arrayFollowersIds, $followersArray['ids']);
    }
    else {
        // An error ocurred
        break;
    }
}

// Show all user ids
var_dump($arrayFollowersIds);
```

The for loop has a limit because as you can see in the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids), you are only allowed to make 15 calls every 15 minutes. You will have to store ids for big accounts and merge them later.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Alberto **Thanks for your input**, you are absolutely right. Your reply led me to new way wasn't in my mind. First, get all IDs using followers/ids, then use user/lookup to bring users' details.

Comment: Yes, that's all. Just remember Twitter API Limits @Nabeel